# Register a celery PeriodicTask after it's created and at runtime

Tags: python, django, celery

My application creates `PeriodicTask` objects according to user-defined schedules. That is, the schedule for the PeriodicTask can change at any time. The past couple days have been spent in frustration trying to figure out how to get Celery to support this. Ultimately, the issue is that, for something to run as a `PeriodicTask` it first, has to be created and then second, has to be registered (I have no idea why this is required).

So, for dynamic tasks to work, I need

1. to register all the tasks when the celery server starts
2. to register a task when it is newly created.

#1 should be solved easily enough by running a startup script (i.e., something that gets run after ./manage.py celerybeat gets called). Unfortunately, I don't think there's a convenient place to put this. If there were, the script would go something like this:

```
from djcelery.models import PeriodicTask
from celery.registry import tasks
for task in PeriodicTask.objects.filter(name__startswith = 'scheduler.'):
  tasks.register(task)
```

I'm filtering for 'scheduler.' because the names of all my dynamic tasks begin that way.

#2 I have no idea. The issue so far as I see it is that `celery.registry.tasks` is kept in memory and there's no way, barring some coding magic, to access the celerybeat's tasks registry once it started running.

Thanks in advance for your help.